# How to hide AspxPopupControl in Page Load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I want to hide Devexpress AspxPopupControl in PageLoad when User Role equal to Person like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (base.User.IsInRole("Person"))          
        {               
           popup1.ShowOnPageLoad = false;
           popup2.ShowOnPageLoad = false;           
        }
}
```

But it is not working ! How can I hide ? I dont want User In Role Person display popup1 and popup2 .

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this :

aspx

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td id="tdPopup1" runat="server">


  popup control 


</td></tr></table>
```

C#

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (base.User.IsInRole("Person"))          
    {               

       tdPopup1.Visible=false;
    }
  }
```